# I created a long List view with Listview.Builder() Widget Sucessfully but where context and index come from inside itemBuilder: (context, index)?

Tags: flutter, dart

**strong text**  I use the below code to Create  A long list view using Listview.builder() method but i don't understand where context, and index come from inside **itembuilder(context, index)**

If you can see the code below  Listview.builder() returns a list of ListTile(), by using  itemBuilder context,and  index,   **itemBuilder:(context,index)**  but where this context and index is come from.. please help??

Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "loglist",
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("longlist"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: getlonglist(),
    ),
  ));
}

List<String> stringlist = List<String>.generate(50, (items) {
  return "item $items";
});


Widget getlonglist() {
  Widget listitembuilder = ListView.builder( 
      **itemBuilder: (context, index)** {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(stringlist[index]),
    );
  });
  return listitembuilder;
}
```

Comment: they are provided by the listview its self, index is usually iterated on from 0 to the number of items specified in itemsCount in the listview. I think you forgot to put itemsCount property for the listview if you are getting an error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code just add `itemCount: stringlist.length,` inside your ListView

refer documentation for **long lists** [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "loglist",
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("longlist"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: getlonglist(),
    ),
  ));
}

List<String> stringlist = List<String>.generate(50, (items) {
  return "item $items";
});


Widget getlonglist() {
  Widget listitembuilder = ListView.builder( 
    itemCount: stringlist.length,
    shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index)   {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(stringlist[index]),
    );
  });
  return listitembuilder;
}
```

Your result-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how the flutter has created the [listview.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) constructor. itemBuilder is a required arg which is of type [IndexWidgetBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedWidgetBuilder.html) which requires an index and a buildcontext.

In order to let the itembuilder know how many items are present use `itemCount`

Comment: Ok Brother Thank you i understand where index comes and what it is, But what is the advantages of context, inside itemBuilder(context, index)